# mod_rewrite everything except two URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite everything EXCEPT the below two urls to
google.com (could be any external url, but google for testing).

```
w3ink.com/wp/folder/wp-admin  
w3ink.com/wp/folder/schedule-the-truck
```

goes to pages on site.

everything else goes to google.com

Here's what I have so far in my .htaccess file in documentRoot:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/folder/schedule-the-truck$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/folder/wp-admin$  
RewriteRule .* "http://google.com" [R=301,L]
```

It just doesn't work. Everything gets forwarded to google.com, even the two pages in my negative condition statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable the `mod_rewrite` debug logging. This might probably show you that for `.htaccess` files, the `REQUEST_URI` does not start with a slash. (And even if my assumption is wrong, it will show you all steps that happen, which should give you a hint to *why* they happen.

Comment: Based on what I have read about REQUEST_URI, it does start with a slash. The problem is that I am in a shared hosting environment and I am not allowed access to the mod_rewrite debug log. . .It seems like the conditions in my .htaccess file are not even evaluated. . .

Comment: So you think that normal rules are evaluated, but only this rule with its conditions is not? In that case you can try the following combination: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)` with `RewriteRule . http://www.google.com/search?q=%1 [R,L]`. Then you know at least what's in `REQUEST_URI`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `$` at the end of the rewrite conditions.

Because `wp-admin` is a directory, the server redirected to `wp-admin/`. Then your rewrite rule redirected that to `http://www.google.com/`.